# Out of Memory in Cycles when changing render engines

Tags: rendering

When i change render engine to cycles it can't render until i reboot blender. This is caused because of a high res textures.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Could you convert this to a question, somehow? .. 'How do I A, B, C, given X, Y, Z'?

Comment: Can you include what kind of GPU you have?